# The 'Load More Articles' button at the bottom of my blog(Wordpress), etc. keep re-loading the same articles

Tags: wordpress, post, load, blogs, article

I actually have a bug that I need to be fixed. Maybe. The 'Load More Articles' button at the bottom of my blog, etc. keeps re-loading the same articles. How to fix this bug?
Here is the link:
https://www.bazartravels.com/blog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Share ajax code that load posts. Probably problem lying there.

Comment: You have included js file loadmore.js so in functions.php you propably have code like this:
`wp_enqueue_script('loadmore', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/loadmore.js', array('jquery'), false,  1);`
and `wp_localize_script('loadmore'` post it here